Blazor 8 MudBlazor Tooltip Y position incorrect after scrolling the page
I have an issue with the following MudTooltip:
<MudTooltip Text="@Loc["HistoryTooltip"]" Delay="1000" Placement="Placement.Top">
    <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.History" Color="Color.Default" />
</MudTooltip>

The tooltip shows, but if I scroll the page it shows only at the original position, not at the new position after scrolling... This is in InteractiveServer mode.
Am I doing something wrong, or missing something? I cannot be the only one who ever encountered this issue...

I managed to get it working by applying the following CSS:
.mud-popover-cascading-value {
    position: fixed;
}

The tooltip now follows the scrolling or page resize properly.
